# MVVM and Managing Arrays

Tags: angular, mvvm, observable

I currently am trying to implement the Model view view-model paradigm and feel like I'm doing it incorrectly. On my Angular component, I have the following:

```
dataModel[] = [];
viewModel[] = [];
```

I have a response that comes back from a service of which I populate the `dataModel` with. I then essentially copy the contents of the `dataModel` to the `viewModel` and add some more properties to it to be used during rendering.

Anytime I make a change to my `dataModel`, I'd like for those changes to be reflected in the `viewModel` as well but without having to manually perform actions on each of these arrays.

For example, I may delete something from my `dataModel` but then also do the same action on my `viewModel` and it feels like a code smell.

Should I be using Observables to listen to changes in my `dataModel` to decide when to alter items in my `viewModel` ?

Comment: Why do you need both of these?

Comment: angular (2/4/5) ins not mvvm. so you should think in the way of chain of components

Comment: I thought I would need to be handling both of these in order to have a separation of concerns. Should I just first get all of my `data` and then transform that array and use the same one for rendering on my template? @ExplosionPills

Comment: It depends on how big the transformation is. You don't have to enforce this style everywhere, but it's not a bad thing to do if the model that you need for creation of view is too different from the one you get from API (such as doing joins or removing duplicates based on some criteria).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observables certainly *are* an option here. If your `dataModel$` is an observable, the `viewModel$` observable is simply its transformation, and they will always stay in sync:

```
viewModel$ = dataModel$.map(data => /* transform */)
```

You can also do it by leveraging setters, but you'll have to enforce immutable style in order to invoke the setter.

```
private _viewModel
public set viewModel(viewModel) {
  this.dataModel = transform(viewModel)
  this._viewModel = viewModel
}
public get viewModel() { return this._viewModel }
```

Comment: This is really great! Coincidentally, others were doing something similar in the code-base I'm working with